# Error using PHP code in Aptana

Tags: php, aptana

I am trying to add just a simple hello world type of PHP code using Aptana 3.0.  The editor is giving me an error.  I have looked at several examples of PHP code on the internet and I am not sure what the editor does not like.  Here is the sample code.

```
<?php
    echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

The Aptana editor gives me the following error.

> "' for end of tag

I am not sure what to make of it.  I am probably missing something simple but I am not sure what it is.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are inserting PHP code in a file whose type is not PHP or editing a .php file with a wrong editor.

Check that it's a PHP file and/or right-click on your file and select "Open With" -> "Other ..." -> "PHP Source Editor".